# PHP: Is there any Bluetooth RFCOMM library?

Tags: php, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on an Arduino Project. The bluetooth slave I have for arduino is RFCOMM based. I am looking to program in PHP and would like to know if there are any Bluetooth RFCOMM libraries.

Thank You
Sunil

UPDATE:
For some reason I am not able to make the php-class work! The command line from windows works! Linux doesnt! All I am doing in my Arduino program is check for 1 or 0 from the serial port and transferring this over the serial port. I am using cable initially as I am not able to connect the bluetooth RFCOMM device to my windows machine. It detects the bluetooth assigns a COM port. But probabl I need to initiate a connection which I am not able to figure out!

Comment: Why PHP? This has nothing to do with web servers.

Comment: I don't think PHP is the right choice for Ardunio programming. (As for embedded programming at all) PHP is simply not designed to be used on or for embedded devices and I don't think you will find very much to support it. It doesn't mean it won't work, but you certainly choose a more difficult path than directly programming on a lower, better suited language like C or C++. And if you do it with php you most likely won't get around cross compiling everything specially for arduino.

Comment: I was looking for a better interface and that is why I chose PHP and not C. I will be sending the instructions like move forward, reverse, left or right over bluetooth with the button click events! I am more into web based and wanted to extend it over the web

Answer (score 1):

Pair the device with the server and use [php-serial](http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/) to communicate over the created serial port.

Comment: Thank you Ignacio. I tried using php-serial. While I call the sendMessage, the Rx Tx in Arduino blinks  but it doesnot update the value. I have matching bit rates for the serial ports. When I do echo 1 to com4 from Windows cmd after setting the mode, the program functions as I want. just that the php-class sendMessage is not functioning! Probably some mistake from my end but I am doing this with the example code provided!